# Trying index characters in strings and create new strings

Tags: c++

I'm currently making a quick Hangman game and I'm struggling to take the correctly guessed letters from the word and insert them into the string that I show the user as they play the game. This is my code so far:

```
std::string word_to_guess = "ataamataesaa";
    std::string word_to_fill(word_to_guess.length(), '-');
    char user_guess = 'a';

    for (auto &character : word_to_guess) {
        if (character == user_guess) {
            std::size_t index = word_to_guess.find(&character); 
            word_to_fill[index] = user_guess;
        }
    }

    std::cout << word_to_fill;
```

This almost works however it ignores the last two As of the string to guess which I cannot understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Find" will return only the first occurrence.

Instead of iterating over characters, iterate simultaneously over the indexes of both word_to_guess and word_to_fill.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < word_to_fill.length ; ++i) {
    if (word_to_guess[i] == user_guess) {
        word_to_fill[i] = user_guess;
    }
}
```